# Why does my firebase database child return null?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am working with firebase database and i was trying to get the value of a child using this code below and may `System.out.println(MyCredit.toString());` is always returns null: [Please see my firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22F9w.jpg)

```
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //Get map of users in datasnapshot
                        CollectCredits((Map<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        //handle databaseError
                    }
                });



private void CollectCredits(Map<String,Object> users) {

         MyCredit = new ArrayList<>();

        //iterate through each user, ignoring their UID
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : users.entrySet()){

            //Get user map
            Map singleUser = (Map) entry.getValue();
            //Get Credit field and append to list
            MyCredit.add((Long) singleUser.get("Credit"));

            Toast.makeText(MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.this, "Credit : " +String.valueOf(MyCredit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

        System.out.println(MyCredit.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void CollectCredits(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

         MyCredit = new ArrayList<>();

        //iterate through each dataSnapshot
        for (DataSnapshot d1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            MyCredit.add(d1.getValue());

        }
}
```

Comment: i have used the code above by error comes ```java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot```

Comment: the thing is my Displayname's child is my usersname  which has a child credit . . i want to get the value of the credit

Comment: Can you tell me what do you get the value of d1.getValue() in the log?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you some suggestions, Try to check your firebase database path both the root and child path because some time you did everything correctly but the path you specified to your Database reference which is not referring to the correct path. So it can produce the same result what are getting right now.